# Measure runtime of algorithm on a spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

How do I measure the runtime of an algorithm in spark, especially  on a cluster?  I am interested in measuring the time from when the spark job is submitted to the cluster to when the submitted job has completed.

If it is important, I am mainly interested in machine learning algorithms using dataframes.

Comment: what do you mean correctly? What solutions have you tried that gave incorrect answers?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience a reasonable approach is to measure the time from the submission of job to the completion on the driver. This is achieved by surrounding the spark *action* with timestamps:

```
 val myRdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://foo/bar/..")
 val startt = System.currentTimeMillis
 val cnt = myRdd.count()  // Or any other "action" such as take(), save(), etc
 val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis - startt
```

Notice that the initial `sc.textFile()` is **lazy** - i.e. it does not cause spark driver to submit the job to the cluster. therefore it is not really important if you include that in the timing or not.

A consideration for the results:  the approach above is susceptible to variance due to existing load on the spark scheduler and cluster. A more precise approach would include the spark job writing the

```
System.currentTimeMillis
```

inside of its closure (executed on worker nodes) to an Accumulator at the beginning of its processing. This would remove the scheduling latency from the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the runtime of an algorithm, follow this procedure-

1. establish a single/multi node cluster
2. Make a folder and save your algorithm in that folder (eg. myalgo.scala/java/pyhton)

3.build it using sbt (you can follow this link to build your program. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BeTWT8ADfE)

4.Run this command: SPARK_HOME$ /bin/spark-submit --class "class name" --master "spark master URL" "target jar file path" "arguments if any"

For example- spark-submit --class "GroupByTest" --master spark://BD:7077 /home/negi/sparksample/target/scala-2.11/spark-sample_2.11-1.0.jar

After this, refresh your web UI(eg. localhost:8080) and you will get all information there about your executed program including run-time.